# c - How to make whole string uppercase, if it contains numbers?

Tags: c, string, c-strings

So I need to make a string uppercase + remove spaces from it. It however doesn't work, if the string contains numbers, the final print prints some non-ascii chars. How should I make it work? I tried to do it with functions `isalpha()` and `isdigit()`, but the result is the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    char c[100];
    char str[] = "Hello8 world";

    while(str[i]){
        if (str[i]!=' '){
            if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9'){
                c[i]=str[i];
            }
            else{
                c[i]=(toupper(str[i]));
            }
        i++;
        }
   }
   printf("%s", c);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: "It however doesn't work, if the string contains numbers, the final print prints some non-ascii chars." -- That's not what your code is doing. Your code, for the string you put in your question, enters an infinite loop. Please decide *which* code you need help with. Is it this code? Then make the question text match the code's behaviour. Is it some other code? Then post some other code.

Comment: You do *not* need to make numbers a special case. [`toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) only changes alphabetic characters and leaves all others unchanged.

Comment: @hdv You are right, I kind of expected the part that is supposed to not let the space go into the new string to work. The infinite loop is caused by the if (str[i]!=' '){, what would you suggest?

Comment: @AnetaKožoušková, why you don't use bitwise operation? it is fast and elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong here. First, you only advance `i` inside the `if` statement, so once you encounter a space, your problem will get stuck in an endlees loop.
Second, you assume the index in the source and target string are the same - which is not true, since you're skipping spaces. This will cause the target string to keep unitialized memory - which could be `\0` on some platforms, and could just be random junk on others. Instead, you should maintain two index counters, one for the source and one for the target, and explicitly set `\0` at the end of the target when you're done:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0; /* Target string index */
char c[100];
char str[] = "Hello8 world";

while(str[i]){
    if (str[i]!=' '){ 
        if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9'){
            c[i]=str[i];
        }
        else{
            c[j]=(toupper(str[i]));
        }
        j++; /* Target index advance only when it's used */
    }
    i++; /* Source index advanced regardless */
}
c[j] = '\0'; /* Handle the string termination */
printf("%s\n", c);
```

Answer (score 1):

1-You don't need to create another string.
2-The toupper() function don't turn digits to something else.
3-If you find a space you just need to pull the rest of the string.

```
int i = 0, j;
char str[] = "Hello8 world";

while(str[i]!='\0')
{
    if(str[i]==' ')
    {   
        for(j=i;str[j]!='\0';j++)
        {
            str[j]=str[j+1];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        str[i]=toupper(str[i]);
        i++;
    }

}

printf("%s\n", str);

return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

After the `while` loop, add `c[i] = '\0';`.

This will convert the character array into a string (which, by definition, must have `\0` as a terminator).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a for loop, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXCHAR 100

int
main(void) {
    char str[] = "Hello8 world";
    char upper[MAXCHAR];
    int str_pos = 0, i;

    for (i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        if (!isspace(str[i])) {
            upper[str_pos++] = toupper(str[i]);
        }
    }
    upper[str_pos] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", upper);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can try this simpler approach @Aneta Kožoušková